# BigQuery Data Transfer for CM360

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, data-transfer, google-bigquery-storage-api

I am currently trying to do a BigQuery Data Transfer for CM360. My Google Account Manager has placed the Data Transfer files into a Google cloud storage (GCS) bucket. Access to the GCS bucket is managed by a Google Group of which i am admin of, BUT the bucket is not assigned to any Project. In order for me to link the bucket to my BigQuery, the bucket needs to be assigned to a Project (and then i can open the Project in BigQuery with the bucket assigned to it).

Question: How do i assign the bucket that the google acc manager created for me into a Project so i can open it in my BiqQuery?

I gave the Google Group email access to a Project, but nothing is showing up.